# Multiple nested resources with multiple methods are not displayed in Django Rest Framework Documentation

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I wonder why Django REST Framework build-in documentation doesn't display methods for a `User`. I have only available `list`, `create`, `read`, `update` for these URLs:

```
url(r'^users$', views.UserList.as_view()),
url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>\w+)$', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
```

views.py:

```
@permission_classes([CustomPermission])
class UserList(GenericAPIView):

    """
    get: Return all users.
    post: Create a user.
    """

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request):

        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@permission_classes([UserPermission])
class UserDetail(GenericAPIView):

    """
    get: Return user by ID.
    put: Update user by ID.
    delete: Delete user by ID.
    """

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request, user_id):

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, user_id):

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save()
          return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, user_id):

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

However example shown below is not visible in build-in documentation. I have also Swagger documentation in the project and everything is displayed properly.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/object$', views.UserObject.as_view()),
```

views.py:

```
@permission_classes([UserPermission])
class UserObject(GenericAPIView):

    """
    post: Create a user object by his ID.
    get: Return a user object by his ID.
    put: Update a user object by his ID.
    delete: Delete a user object by his ID.
    """

    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer

    def post(self, request, user_id):

        try:
            Object.objects.get(user=user_id)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)


        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            serializer = ObjectSerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.fields['user'].required = False
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save(user_id=user_id)
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    def get(self, request, user_id):
        try:
            object = Object.objects.get(user=user_id)
        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = ObjectSerializer(object)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, user_id):
        try:
            object = Object.objects.get(user=user_id)
        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = ObjectSerializer(object, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, user_id):
        try:
            object = Object.objects.get(user=user_id)
        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        object.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

There should be visible path `users/{user_id}/object` Any idea why is not?

[image]

Comment: Hey, I don't understand quite well which url's are working and which ones are not.
Is  `UserObject` not working? Do you have any other one working?

Have you tried documenting exactly as the doc say: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/#documenting-your-views

Comment: Are you saying that when you visit your Swagger documentation page everything is documented as expected, but when you visit an endpoint itself, you don't see the DRF GUI? Or something else?

Comment: @Willemoes there is a problem only with `url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/object$', views.UserObject.as_view()),` The rest works properly.

Comment: @YPCrumble I don't see only `url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/object$', views.UserObject.as_view()),` The rest is visible as on the screenshot in updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2017-08-19**

I've made a [PR with the fix](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5334) which has already been merged. So may be try to get latest version.

**Edit 2017-08-13**

This is a [bug](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4391) with DRF default documentations, where extra actions with more than one method are not displayed in the docs.

Solution: use [swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger)

**Original**

I tried reproducing it, looks like there is a bug in the `coreapi` from `django-rest-framework`.

I've tried with the doc generator [swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) for rest-framework and it looks fine.

There is a bug in the `url` if you remove `object` from `users/{user_id}/object` it works. If you try for example `xsers/{user_id}/` it'll work.

[image: swagger example]

You could change the design approach using a ViewSet. 
ViewSet provides `actions` instead of mapping directly to the `method`. It's another level of abstraction, usually clearer.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    retrieve:
    Return the given user. 

    list:
    Return a list of all the existing users.

    create:
    Create a new user instance.

    update:
    Update a user.
    """

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        # Here you should put the code for GET user/
        pass

    def create(self, request):
        # Here you should put the code for POST user/
        pass

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        # Here you should put the code for RETRIEVE user/{pk}
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        # Here you should put the code for UPDATE user/{pk}
        pass

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def objects(self, request, pk=None):
        if request.method == 'GET'
        ....
```

And in your urls

```
from myapp.views import UserViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

More info http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: For now try changing the doc generator tool, instead of using the drf default one, try using swagger, I've provided the link up there, it says how to install and configure, quite straightforward

Comment: I have Swagger documentation now but I would like to have DRF, too. The only idea that comes to my mind is to try create one view for all paths that begin with `/users`

Comment: If you ask me... I'd use a ViewSet, where you define `list` (for GET user/), `create` (for POST user/) , `retrieve` (for a GET user/{pk}) and `update` (for PATCH user/{pk}, and the `object` in the last url is an `action` inside the `user` resource, for that you should define a `detail_route` check here how to use http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing, with that, the docs would be generated correctly

Comment: I tried to do it using `ViewSets` unfortunately without results. I have never used it before so I'm not sure how can I achieve my goal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151776/discussion-between-willemoes-and-wahtdbogh).